# Dynamic Timer Application: Create and Manage Multiple Timers(DOM manipulation javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, frontend

**Problem Description:**

I am working on building a dynamic timer application using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. The goal of this project is to allow users to create multiple timers and manage them effectively. However, I am facing some challenges in the implementation, and I would appreciate some guidance to overcome these issues.

**Functional Requirements:**

1. Timer Creation: The application should provide a user-friendly interface to set up a new timer. Users can input the desired timer duration in hours, minutes, and seconds and create a new timer accordingly.
2. Timer Display: Each active timer should be displayed on the screen with a countdown showing the remaining time. The timer should update every second to reflect the accurate time remaining.
3. Audio Alert: When a timer ends, an audio alert should be played to notify the user that the timer has completed.
4. Timer Deletion: Users should be able to remove timers that are no longer needed. When a timer is deleted, it should be stopped, and its corresponding display should be removed from the screen.

**Current Implementation:**

I have already made some progress and have included the relevant code snippets for reference. The application is using the **`Timer`** class to manage individual timers. The **`update()`** method calculates the remaining time for each active timer and updates the display accordingly. Additionally, I have set up an array **`timers`** to keep track of all active timers.

**Challenges:**

1. Displaying Multiple Timers: I have successfully implemented the creation of new timers and added corresponding display elements to the DOM. However, I am struggling to display the time remaining for each timer in its respective **`div`** element with class **`time-left`**. Currently, only the time for the first timer is being displayed, and subsequent timers are not updating their countdown.
2. Timer Deletion: While I have implemented the ability to delete a timer and remove its display element from the DOM, I am concerned about the proper handling of stopping the timer when it is deleted. I want to ensure that the timer is entirely stopped and no longer consumes resources once deleted.

**Desired Outcome:**

I am seeking assistance in resolving the issues mentioned above. Specifically, I would like to understand how to update the display for each active timer and properly handle the timer stoppage upon deletion.

Any insights, code examples, or suggestions to enhance the application's functionality and improve the user experience would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your valuable assistance!

```
I have tried but I think I made error. Please help me out.
```

Project link: [https://letsmailvjkumar.github.io/timerApp/[enter](https://letsmailvjkumar.github.io/timerApp/%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3ibk.png)

```
class Timer {
    constructor(endTime, bottomContainerElement) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.interval = null;
    }

    start() {
        // Start the timer by calling update() every second
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.update(), 1000);
    }

    stop() {
        // Stop the timer by clearing the interval
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }

    update() {
        // Calculate the time remaining
        const timeRemaining = this.endTime - new Date();
        const textChange = document.querySelector('.show-time');
        if (timeRemaining <= 0) {
            // Timer has ended
            // Play audio alert
            // Change timer display to match Figma design
            // Stop the timer
            
            const audio = new Audio('./alert.mp3');
            audio.play();
            this.stop();
        } else {
            // Timer is still active
            // Update timer display with time remaining
            // Calculate the remaining hours, minutes, and seconds
            textChange.textContent = "Current timers";
            const hours = Math.floor(timeRemaining / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            const minutes = Math.floor((timeRemaining % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            const seconds = Math.floor((timeRemaining % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            // Format the remaining time as a string
            const timeLeftStr = `${hours.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;

            // Update the time-left element with the remaining time
            const timeLeftElement = document.querySelector('.time-left');
            timeLeftElement.textContent = timeLeftStr;
        }
    }
}
let timers = [];


function addTimer() {
    const timeInput = document.getElementById('btn-set');
    timeInput.addEventListener('click', () => {
       
        const timeValue = document.getElementById('time').value; // Get the time input value

        // Split the time value into hours, minutes, and seconds
        const [hours, minutes, seconds] = timeValue.split(':').map(Number);

        // Calculate the end time as the current time plus the input hours, minutes, and seconds
        const endTime = new Date();
        endTime.setHours(endTime.getHours()+hours);
        endTime.setMinutes(endTime.getMinutes()+minutes);
        endTime.setSeconds(endTime.getSeconds()+seconds);


        
        // Create a new Timer object and start it
        const timer = new Timer(endTime);
        timer.start();
        

        timers.push(timer);
        
         // Update the timers display
         updateTimers();
    });
}
addTimer();

function updateTimers() {
    
    // Get the time-left-container element
    const timeLeftContainerElement = document.querySelector('#time-left-container');

    // Remove all existing bottom-container elements
    timeLeftContainerElement.innerHTML = '';

    // Iterate over the timers array and create a new bottom-container element for each timer
    for (const timer of timers) {
        // Create a new bottom-container element for the timer
        const bottomContainerElement = document.createElement('div');
        bottomContainerElement.classList.add('bottom-container');
        bottomContainerElement.innerHTML = `
            <div class="time-remaining">Time Left: </div>
            <div class="time-left">hh:mm:ss</div>
            <div class="time-button">
                <button class="btn-del">Delete</button>
            </div>
        `;

        // Add an event listener to the 'Delete' button
        const deleteButton = bottomContainerElement.querySelector('.btn-del');
        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Stop the timer
            timer.stop();

            // Remove the timer from the timers array
            const index = timers.indexOf(timer);
            timers.splice(index, 1);

            // Remove the bottom-container element
            bottomContainerElement.remove();
        });

        // Append the new bottom-container element to the time-left-container element
        timeLeftContainerElement.appendChild(bottomContainerElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this as a browser app, if so there are some challenges that are really tricky to handle if not impossible, like keeping timers running when the app is not the foreground, playing audio without user interaction etc.  But if your willing to make into a native app, things like electron don't have those limitations.

Comment: https://letsmailvjkumar.github.io/timerApp/

Comment: please share the complete code or repo link